# What are the Ranked play rewards for each rank?

Tags: hearthstone

Hearthstone recently added [additional rewards](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19843158/the-grand-tournament%E2%84%A2-now-available-8-24-2015) for Ranked play based on your highest rank achieved during a season.  Here is some text from the announcement:

*Each player’s Quest Log will display the highest rank they have reached during the month and recognize their accomplishment. Players who progress beyond rank 20 will receive a treasure chest containing an array of nifty little rewards as a way of congratulating them for their achievements. Eligible players will receive their treasure chest at the end of each season containing the season’s Ranked Play card back, one or more golden cards, and some extra Arcane Dust. What’s in the chest is determined by your highest rank over the course of the season.*

Is there a list of per-rank rewards available for reference? Assuming that there are reward "tiers" as in Arena, it would be useful to know at which ranks the rewards improve significantly over the previous rank.

Comment: From my understanding, there are hard breakpoints for what tier of chest you get. However, the contents of that chest appear to be semi-random. Hopefully someone with some evidence can provide a real answer.

Comment: This is my understanding as well. The only thing determined by your rank would probably be the amount you get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of cards and the rarity is fixed, the actual cards you get is random.

```
Rank 20-16: 1 golden common
Rank 15-11: 1 golden common, 1 golden rare
Rank 10-6:  2 golden common, 1 golden rare
Rank 5-1:   2 golden common, 1 golden epic
legend:     3 golden common, 1 golden epic
```

Additionally you get between 5-25 dust.

The important thresholds are rank 15 and rank 5. On rank 15 you get a golden rare (100 dust), and on rank 5 you get a golden epic (400 dust).

[Source](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ranked)

Answer (score 15):

According to http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/18700821475?page=1 the rewards are as follows:

Rank 20 - 1 golden common card, 5 dust
Rank 19 - 1 golden common card, 10 dust
Rank 18 - 1 golden common card, 15 dust
Rank 17 - 1 golden common card, 20 dust
Rank 16 - 1 golden common card, 25 dust
Rank 15 - 1 golden common card, 1 golden rare card, 5 dust
Rank 14 - 1 golden common card, 1 golden rare card, 10 dust
Rank 13 - 1 golden common card, 1 golden rare card, 15 dust
Rank 12 - 1 golden common card, 1 golden rare card, 20 dust
Rank 11 - 1 golden common card, 1 golden rare card, 25 dust
Rank 10 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden rare card, 5 dust
Rank 9 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden rare card, 10 dust
Rank 8 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden rare card, 15 dust
Rank 7 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden rare card, 20 dust
Rank 6 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden rare card, 25 dust
Rank 5 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card, 5 dust
Rank 4 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card, 10 dust
Rank 3 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card, 15 dust
Rank 2 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card, 20 dust
Rank 1 - 2 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card, 25 dust
Legendary - 3 golden common cards, 1 golden epic card